# Split a string into unevenly sized chunks in a repeating pattern

Tags: python, python-2.7, split

I have a string representing a series of bits:

```
bit_stream = "10100101011101011101011"  # ...(so on)
```

I need to split this into unevenly sized chunks in a repeating pattern. The first chunk should be length 1, followed by a chunk of length 8, then a chunk of length 2, and so on until the bits are exhausted:

```
result = ["1", "01001010", "11", "1", "01011101", "01", "1"]  # ...(so on)
```

Comment: What is this (1,8,2) format? Please give a brief description if possible or a link... Also you are expected to show what you've tried.

Comment: I mean the (1,8,2) format is something like this : 
'[1, 01001010, 11, 1, 010101, 01, 1..(so on)]'
 ^  ^^^^^^^^^    ^^
 1  ---8-------     2-

Comment: Are you suggesting that 1 = 1, 8 = 01001010, and 2 = 11? If so, then can you explain how you're coming up with this mapping?

Comment: Yes @Austin A, that's what I meant. Its just a stream of bits to be translated to ASCII. 1 means start bit, 8 is the data and 2 is the stop bit.

Comment: Am I understanding correctly that (1, 8, 2) are the length of the substrings to split? and what type should the resulting list contain?

Comment: It seems to me that (1,8,2) is some type of array containing bit lengths for the data in bit_stream

Comment: @JulienBernu, result must be like this, result = [1,01001010,11,1,010101,01,1..(so on)] from the series of bit_stream data

Comment: @Renée Repeating the same information, over and over again isn't helpful. This is not a well formulated question and it's clear that you haven't taken an appropriate amount of time for self reflection of this problem. In the future, I would suggest referring to SO's suggestions on [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Renée I think (hope) I've understood you and you've got good, working answers below, but I must admit I initially voted "Unclear what you're asking" on your question. It was hard to determine from what you posted that you meant "Divide this into unevenly sized chunks of the specified lengths, repeating" and it doesn't help that your example output fails your own criteria! (One of your bit strings that should be 8-bit is actually 6.)

Comment: @AustinA, noted. Thanks for reminding me! I'll do better next time sir.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist, thanks, I edited it sir. Thanks for your answer, it helps me a lot. Next time I'll formulate my question more clearer and concise.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist, yes sir! Already marked! I cannot up vote your answer and Mark Tolonen since my reputation still low. Thanks again! Have a great day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did this similarly to the other answer posted about a minute ago but I didn't use a class to track state.

```
import itertools

def alternating_size_chunks(iterable, steps):
    n = 0
    step = itertools.cycle(steps)
    while n < len(iterable):
        next_step = next(step)
        yield iterable[n:n + next_step]
        n += next_step
```

Testing:

```
>>> test_string = ''.join(random.choice('01') for _ in range(50))
>>> print(list(alternating_size_chunks(test_string, (1, 8, 2))))
['1', '01111010', '01', '1', '00111011', '11', '0', '11010100', '01', '0', '10011101', '00', '0', '11111']
```

Note that both these methods (mine and Mark's answer) will take an arbitrary set of lengths (whether it's 1, 8, 2 or anything else), and will work even if the length of the bit stream doesn't precisely add up to a multiple of the sum of the lengths. (You can see in my example it ran out of bits and the last chunk only has five.) This may or may not be desirable in your case, so you might want to check that you have enough data to convert once you get ready to do that.

Reference: [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle)

Comment: Thanks, but I got this error when I use your code sir. It says 'NameError: global name 'itertools' is not defined'

Comment: You have to `import itertools` -- edited answer to show an example

Comment: This doesn't match the desired output, which has lengths [1, 8, 2, 1, 10, 1, 2]. Apparently you should't assume that [1, 8, 2] repeats. The "repeating" must mean something else.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist, yeah, I forgot to import that! Thanks! :D

Comment: @StefanPochmann, I edited the list data above so that it will matched the [1, 8, 2] sequence.

Comment: @Renée Still wrong, now they're [1, 8, 2, 1, 8, 1, 2].

Comment: @StefanPochmann, I see. Whoa, thanks for noticing it. I just fixed it.

Comment: @StefanPochmann I think that's a typo in the manually created expected output. OP [clarified in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39283744/split-a-string-into-unevenly-sized-chunks-in-a-repeating-pattern/39283911?noredirect=1#comment65902144_39283744) that the data represents a series of 8-bit ASCII characters delimited by 1- and 2-bit start and stop sequences on either side.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist Hmm, looking at the question edits, I see that its example actually had the correct lengths and then **you** broke that :-)

Comment: @StefanPochmann Haha I noticed that as well. It was midnight and I lost that edit due to a glitch twice so I was getting really tired of retyping it!

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use a class to track state and an iterator to return groups of bits.  `itertools.cycle` is used to generate the bit counts repeatedly:

```
from itertools import cycle

class Bits(object):

    def __init__(self,input_bits,bit_counts):
        self.bits = input_bits
        self.counts = cycle(bit_counts)

    def __iter__(self):
        while self.bits:
            count = next(self.counts)
            bits,self.bits = self.bits[:count],self.bits[count:]
            yield bits

print(list(Bits('10100101011101011101011',(1,8,2))))
```

Output:

```
['1', '01001010', '11', '1', '01011101', '01', '1']
```

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist I like yours better...less string slicing and simpler.

Answer (score 0):

```
bit_stream = "10100101011101011101011"
fmt = [1,8,2]
i = 0
j = 0
lenb = len( bit_stream )
result = []

while True:
    l = j + fmt[i]
    if l < lenb:
        result.append( bit_stream[j:l] )
    else:
        result.append( bit_stream[j:lenb] )
        break
    j = l
    i = i + 1
    if i > 2:
        i = 0
print result
```

Output:

```
['1', '01001010', '11', '1', '01011101', '01', '1']
```

Comment: Just so you know `len` is an O(1) operation in Python (objects store their length on an internal property, at least built-in ones) so it may be clearer to just call `len` everywhere instead of storing it in a local.

Comment: Thanks @Two-BitAlchemist for the info.